# HTML5 date control validation in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using the following HTML 5 date control.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" #dtStartDate="ngModel" id="dtStartDate" name="dtStartDate" 
 [ngModel] ="startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="startDate = $event" required 
 [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': control.submitted && (dtStartDate.invalid || dtStartDate.value > dtEndDate.value) }"
```

[max]="endDate" />

```
  onSubmit(form) {
   
    console.log("Form is " + form.valid);
    if(!form.valid) {
      return

   };
```

There are two issues:

1. I have set max date to endDate. The date picker pop up restricts user to select start date before the endDate. However, the date control allows to change the date using keyboard so there is still a chance that user can set startDate greater than endDate. Is there anyway to restrict this?
2. If there user set startDate greater than endDate. I was thinking form.isValid property will be false. However, it is not the case - the form.isValid is true. Is there any additional property I need to set?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the browser's native input, which although allows for setting a max date limit when selecting, but fails to restrict keyboard input since it does not go by the date picker.
There is not much you can do here, the user will always be able to perform these types of operations.

The best way to handle this is using validators.
Since you want a custom behaviour, you can't use the **TemplateDrivenApproach** (I believe this is what you are using). This is because there is no validator for max date. You can convert the date into a number and use the [Max Validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max) but that will bring you other issues down the road (magic numbers and the like).

So I would recomend switching to a **ReactiveApproach** and create your own [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). This would allow you to implement your own logic regarding the acceptable dates and reuse it if needed.

Comment: thanks for your detailed Answer. Yes, I am using TemplateDrivenApproach. If I switch to Reactive Approach, will form.IsValid return false if dates are not valid?

Comment: If you switch to a ReactiveApproach you can create a custom validation. This custom validator will have the logic that you want. You can make so that if the dates are not valid, that the form.isValid returns false. So I would say yes, but you need to create the custom validator.